# How to retrieve a selected text of Gtk TextView

Tags: c#, gtk

I have a GTK `TextView` and I need to put selected text into a string, how can I do that?

There is event SelectionGet, but it doesn't seem to work. (Never triggered)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Selection
{
   get
   {
       Gtk.TextIter A;
       Gtk.TextIter B;
       if (textView.Buffer.GetSelectionBounds(out A, out B))
       {
           return textView.Buffer.GetText(A, B, true);
       }
       // return null when there is no selection
       return null;
   }
}
```